Save & Auto-Save Disaster
I've just lost 8 hours worth of work. Neither my manual save or auto-save worked. I manually saved often using ctrl-s. My auto-save was set to every 2 minutes. After Blender crashed at 9pm,my only auto save available was from 1pm. When Blender crashed, it just closed without warning. It did not give me a (not responding) window. My PC performance was smooth from my task manager window at the time.
I suppose I've got two questions:

Has anyone some tips regarding auto-save? Any add-ons or preferences to give extra security to the blender saving system?

Has anyone here ever experienced this type of problem before? Did it end up being blenders fault or your PC's fault?



I never relied on auto save, but what surprises me most is that you say you "manually saved often using ctrl-s", this had never failed me. I can only imagine that the manual save gets corrupted if Blender crashes while saving the file. But for important projects I save different steps inbetween in a new file, so that I can back to earlier stages and not all the files will be corrupted then, just the last one.

as Gordon already wrote - manual save works. But of course you should not overwrite always the same file - you still have a chance that there is a blend1 file. I personally use save incremental. more infos here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7egoV6YmSJo

Glad that you were able to recover.  I simply sync my projects folder to Google drive with the desktop app, gdrive has the ability to recover previous versions of files, but that assumes you have let it upload fully between changes.  I have very fast upload so this is never a problem.

I find it weird that - with an autosave every 2 minutes, you are left with only one autosave file from 8 hours prior to crash. Has your original file disappeared or got corrupted (if so, try appending its content first)? If all is left is an autosave, are you sure you looked it up in the right place?
On Windows you should find autosaves in %TEMP%. You can type that in the system file explorer, and then in the file searchbar type *.blend to see only .blend file.
If you enabled Save Versions, anytime you save your file it keeps a copy of the X previous save as a *.blend# file, alongside the original file.
Now to be honest, if you do anything serious in a file, relying on a single save point is a recipe for disaster. Because it doesn't take much for one save to be lost (data loss, corruption, crash, ...). Autosave and Save Versions are mere additional safety nets, but not that reliable: autosaves are in the system's temp folder. It's a place that can be wiped out by the system or other softwares. Blender's versioning is limited to only a few numbers, and it creates a new file extension for each of them which is annoying to deal with.
The most basic and safer way is to actively keep a history of your saves. Instead of saving the same file over and over, use incremental saving, either from the File menu or the save PIE menu. If you already have the reflex of saving often, making incremental saves will really save you, because even if the current file and the autosave is lost, you'd still have all the previous saves you made regularly.
If you work on complex projects on a professional level, it'd be also time to consider having a version control software, and a redundant storage. Redundancy starts with saving multiple files, like incremental saving. It can be also to save on multiple drives, a NAS with raid >0 , or on the cloud like Google Drive, Onedrive, Dropbox and whatnot (which do offer some version control features I think).

Below text is made heavily using AI because it's annoying to write this much by phone and I don't know all solutions that exist either ;)
A few VCS (Version Control Systems) that are suited for CGI and ita large binary files:
Free and Open Source Solutions:

Git LFS (Large File Storage):

Extends Git to handle large files efficiently by storing file content on a remote server.
Git LFS


Git-annex:

Manages files with Git without checking the file contents into Git, tracking their locations instead.
Git-annex


DVC (Data Version Control):

Tracks large datasets and machine learning models, extending Git's capabilities.
DVC


Apache Subversion (SVN):

Better handles binary files compared to Git and includes features for large files.
Apache Subversion
(I think Blender devs use SVN to carry some of the source libraries necessary for building Blender on Windows)


Mercurial:

More efficient than Git for large files and binary assets.
Mercurial



Other Free Options:

Perforce Helix Core:

Designed for large codebases and binary assets, used in game development.
Free tier for up to 5 users and 20 workspaces.
Perforce Helix Core


Plastic SCM:

Optimized for large files and complex branching, popular in game development.
Free community edition available.
Plastic SCM



These tools provide efficient version control for large files in CGI workflows, balancing the need for detailed tracking with the demands of binary assets.

Thanks for that lots of good info. I was actually able to recover my file by going directly into my file browser and searching %temp%.  For whatever reason, going to file>recover>auto-save won't display anything past 1pm. My next question to you is about redundancy. Is it as simple as just saving it to another drive? I.E. my usb drive and my portable hard drive?

Oh and do you have any recomendations for a version control software? Thanks.

@Scrappy_Bogart Yes, redundancy can be achieved by simply saving to different drives. Even saving several copies to different folders on the same HDD can help, in case of a corrupted file there is hope another one is okay. However in case of a hard drive failure of course everything might be lost, so using different drives if available is the safer way.

I edited my answer

TrueNAS server can also be one extremely good solution if you have the resources to make one(old PC maybe?.. Who doesn't have a few of those lying around?.. :D). Worth considering for a small studio or environment where sharing files and backup is important(in my opinion at least). Next Cloud that works with it also seems very very nice. It's amazing that the software is free.  Not the simplest solution though, but could be cheaper and more flexible than other NAS solutions.

I've seen ppl making their own NAS with raspberry Pi and whatnot. If you know how to connect cables one way or another, its a good option.
